# ClickOnce application Settings vs Administrator Rights (Visual Studio, VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, clickonce, uac, administrator

In Visual Studio (VB.NET), what's the diference between enabling Application ClickOnce Settings, and adding administrator rights to my application (Using application UAC Settings)?

I know that i can not add administrator rights and enable clickonce settings in the same time ... UAC right must be As Invoker when i'm enabling ClickOnce ... So, the ClickOnce Security Settings is the replacement for application Administrator Rights?

Aren't the same things?

Please explain me detailed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The UAC Settings (the `requestedExecutionLevel` setting in the app.manifest) and ClickOnce are two completely separate technologies.

The [requestedExecutionLevel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware) provides a mechanism to set which privileges your application requires in order for it to run as designed

[ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) allows you to publish your application to be installed by the end user by using 'one click'. The user does not necesarily need Admin rights to install your application - *"ClickOnce deployment enables non-administrative users to install and grants only those Code Access Security permissions necessary for the application"*

Note that an end user who is not an administrator could install your application that you deployed using clickOnce, but if you have set the `requestedExecutionLevel` to `requireAdministrator` they would not be able to run it.

Comment: I have a question. In ClickOnce Tab i need that RegistryPermision to be enabled.but when i set it to ''Include'', it says that "The applications will require elevated permissions to run in the selected zone".in conclusion i have to set requestedExecutionLevel to Administrator, no? Doing that i'll be sure that no security exception will crash my application .... but after i have changed the requestedExecutionLevel to Administrator, it says that 'ClickOnce does not support the requested execution level" What i have to do? to enable ClcikOnce, or to set requestedExecutionLevel to Administrator?

Comment: On Windows Vista, when i have tryed to add a key to Registry, thar exception occurs:  System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.   I have to mention that, my application was executed as Administrator